# Helix 3 Logo and Text

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides, helix3

- Joomla 3.6.5
- Helix 3

I am using [this template](http://demo.joomshaper.com/2015/helix3/) and what I am trying to do seems like it should be simple.

Currently I am displaying a logo similar to the default template, however I would also like to include a few words of text below the logo (the site slogan).

I can't find anywhere to do this, I have been searching through the code for specif `<div>` and `id` names but to no avail. I'm not sure what php file to edit.

In the Helix template settings I can only select to either show a logo **or** text - not both.

The html logo code (as you can check for yourself) is as follows;

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-3 col-md-3" id="sp-logo">
    <div class="sp-column">
        <h1 class="logo"><a href="/2015/helix3/"><img alt="Helix3 Framework" class="sp-default-logo" data-pin-nopin="true" src="/2015/helix3/templates/shaper_helix3/images/presets/preset1/logo.png"><img alt="Helix3 Framework" class="sp-retina-logo" height="48" src="/2015/helix3/templates/shaper_helix3/images/presets/preset1/logo@2x.png" width="145"></a></h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Helix don't provise free support which is why I'm here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Link to the template is broken :)

Comment: I've just tried adding a `span` inside the `<a>` in the web inspector and it's working perfectly fine. Are you sure you're editing the correct file? I think it should be `plugins\system\jat3\jat3\base-themes\default\blocks\header.php`

Comment: Oh balls, sorry. Wrong file. Try `templates/shaper_helix3/features/logo.php`

Comment: Oh really? I just downloaded the template and `features` directory was part of the template. Would you be able to zip up the template so I can take a look?

Comment: Hehe no worries :)

Comment: Nah dont worry, you go for it and you'll get my upvote ;)

Comment: Quick question @Lodder - this is all working fine, but will I lose my changes if I update? Do I need to create an override, I'm not sure how. Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can override this file as it's not a layout. Here was someone else trying to override a feature file: https://www.joomshaper.com/forums/helix-3-page-title-override#reply-59117

Comment: Yea I see that :/ - ah well that's a pity. Don't think I'd use another Joomshaper template. Thanks again for the help @Lodder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file I had to edit was located at `templates/shaper_helix3/features/logo.php` (thanks to @Lodder for a point in the right direction!).

In this file at around `line 56` you will see that start of the logo html code. It's possible to add custom html here.

p.s - I initially couldn't see the `templates/shaper_helix3/features` directory as I was using Netbeans and my project had become corrupted. I removed the project and set it up again and the directory was there - strange but it worked.